# Actor getting triggered randomly

Tags: scala, akka, actor, dispatch

I'm running AKKA Actors (version 2.3.9) using Scala API.

I have a bunch of heterogeneous Actors that needs to get triggered every 30 minutes. I see that in a single run, not all the actors are getting triggered. This is completely at random. Each actor doesn't do any heavy-weight tasks so to speak. They make a lot of reads to a NoSQL store and a few writes. Not sure what the actual problem here is. I feel there is somewhere I'm not using the ideal approach.

This is the code:

```
 val system = ActorSystem("pumpkinx-akka")
import system.dispatcher
val noOfActors = 50
val allActors = List(
      system.actorOf(Props[a.actors.TriggerActor].withRouter(new RoundRobinRouter(noOfActors)), "aTriggerActor"),
      system.actorOf(Props[b.actors.TriggerActor].withRouter(new RoundRobinRouter(noOfActors)), "bTriggerActor"),
      system.actorOf(Props[c.actors.TriggerActor].withRouter(new RoundRobinRouter(noOfActors)), "cTriggerActor"),
      system.actorOf(Props[d.actors.TriggerActor].withRouter(new RoundRobinRouter(noOfActors)), "dTriggerActor"),
      system.actorOf(Props[e.actors.TriggerActor].withRouter(new RoundRobinRouter(noOfActors)), "eTriggerActor"))
def trigger = allActors.foreach(_ ! new Start)
system.scheduler.schedule(0 seconds, 30 minutes)(trigger)
system.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Not sure what you expected exactly, you defined RoundRobinRouter and it means not all of them receive the message.

Comment: My expectation is: In a single run, I should be able to send the Start message to all a,b,c,d,e actors - Need not be all the 50 a's. Atleast one 'a' actor would be fine. The problem I see is, 'e' actor is not getting triggered at all sometimes, Likewise, 'b' is not getting triggered at all at times. It's completely at random and difficult to observe a pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have created 5 routers with 50 actors each, so it's 250 `*.actors.TriggerActor`'s. If you want to send a message to all 250 in single run, you should:

```
 def trigger = (1 to 50).foreach(_ => allActors.foreach(_ ! new Start))
```

It will send 50 messages to each router. As it's round robin, first message came to a router will go to its first actor, second - to the second and so on til 50th actor receive a message.

Just `allActors.foreach(_ ! new Start)` only sends a message to one of 50 actors - not to all of them, there is no broadcast. For instance, `a ! Start` just sends the message to one of instances of `a.actors.TriggerActor`

P.S. My modeling:

```
class Trigger extends Actor { 
    def receive = { 
       case x => println(context.parent.path.name + " " + self.path.name + " " + x) 
    }
}
defined class Trigger

val system = ActorSystem("pumpkinx-akka")

val allActors = List(
      system.actorOf(Props[Trigger].withRouter(new RoundRobinRouter(noOfActors)), "aTriggerActor"),
      system.actorOf(Props[Trigger].withRouter(new RoundRobinRouter(noOfActors)), "bTriggerActor"),
      system.actorOf(Props[Trigger].withRouter(new RoundRobinRouter(noOfActors)), "cTriggerActor"),
      system.actorOf(Props[Trigger].withRouter(new RoundRobinRouter(noOfActors)), "dTriggerActor"),
      system.actorOf(Props[Trigger].withRouter(new RoundRobinRouter(noOfActors)), "eTriggerActor"))

scala> allActors.foreach(_ ! "m") //everyone received a message
aTriggerActor $a m
bTriggerActor $a m
cTriggerActor $a m
dTriggerActor $a m
eTriggerActor $a m

scala> (0 to 5).foreach(_ => allActors(1) ! "m") //only to b-router
bTriggerActor $b m //bcdefg (round-robin)
bTriggerActor $g m
bTriggerActor $f m
bTriggerActor $d m
bTriggerActor $e m
bTriggerActor $c m

scala> (0 to 5).foreach(_ => allActors(1) ! "m") //only to b-router
bTriggerActor $h m //hijklm (round-robin)
bTriggerActor $l m
bTriggerActor $j m
bTriggerActor $k m
bTriggerActor $i m
bTriggerActor $m m
```

P.S. Be careful with exceptions inside such routers (inside workers, more precisely). If router is a top-level actor - the failure will be propagated to the guardian, which force the whole system to shutdown.

P.S. If you also want round-robin for heterogeneous actors - use [`RoundRobinGroup`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3-M1/akka/routing/RoundRobinGroup.html), see [examples](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/routing.html)

Comment: My understanding is that each of the "RoundRobinRouter" is for that specific actor only. For example: Router 1 would be for 50 'a' actors, Router 2 would be for 50 'b' actors and so on. I would like to reliably send atleast one message to all 'a','b','c','d','e' actors in a single run. But this is not happening in a deterministic way. Anything I'm missing?

Comment: `allActors.foreach(_ ! new Start)` only sends to a mesasge to one of 50 actors - not to all of them, there is no broadcast. `a ! Start` just sends the message to one of instances of `a.actors.TriggerActor`

Comment: Hmm. I see that. What I don't understand is why is not even a single actor of 'b' gets triggered in a run [For example]

Comment: Could you please show the code (of actors) and input + output (like println in every actor)?

Comment: I mean, ny modeling of this situation (without `system.scheduler.schedule` and with same actor type) shows that 5 actors are invoked

Comment: Thanks very much, that was very clear. I found the actual problem. The issue is with the underlying logic in the actor. The case clause in the couple of actors had an 'if condition' that depended upon the value being updated in the database from another actor. Hence it was completely undeterministic. As a side question, is there anyway I could round robin between heterogeneous actors? For example: In the first run, I want to trigger 'a', in the second run 'b' and so on.

Comment: Yes you can - you need [`RoundRobinGroup`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3-M1/akka/routing/RoundRobinGroup.html) for that. You may read about this [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/routing.html)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75434/discussion-between-user1189332-and-dk14).